# How to get the value of the element selected in ListView JQUERYMOBILE

Tags: jquery-mobile

Hi i'm developping a simple listView that lists the column "firstname" of my table : i want to get the selected value (name) , i found this link but it shows he how to get the index and not the value of the selected item http://jsfiddle.net/w2JZU/

here's my code :

HTML:

```
<div id="popup-bg">
</div>

   <div id="popup-box"> 

   <div data-role="page" id="home">

  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Players</h1>
   </div>

<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="artiste" >
    </ul>    
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

js :

```
    function successCB()
  {
     db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
   }

      function queryDB(tx)
        {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Players ', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
       }

       function querySuccess(tx, results)
         {
          var len = results.rows.length;
           var dataset= results.rows;


         $("#artiste").empty();

          for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
         {  item = dataset.item(i);
           $("#artiste").append( "<li data-theme='c'><a href='game.html'>
          <img src='images/avatar.jpg'><h3>"+item['firstName']+"</h3></a></li>" );

          }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a "value" for an item in a list using the li tag. However, you can get the text of what's in that list element using the jQuery .text() method. I've modified the jsfiddle you referenced to do exactly that: http://jsfiddle.net/Cht2e/

You might want to consider adding another attribute to the li tag, such as data-name (you can make up the attribute) and then you can get that via the jQuery .attr() method. For example, you might change you append code to do:

```
 $("#artiste").append( "<li data-theme='c' data-name='"+item['firstName']+"'><a href='game.html'>
      <img src='images/avatar.jpg'><h3>"+item['firstName']+"</h3></a></li>" );
```

And then attach your click handler like this:

```
$('#artiste').children('li').on('click', function () {
   alert('Selected Name=' + $(this).attr('data-name'));
});
```

I don't think this is necessarily the best structure or approach to take, but it will accomplish what you're asking.

Comment: thank you very  much this really displays the firstName but i'm having a problem with the href tag it tells me "Error Loading Page" so  i changed the url by replacing "href=game.html" by href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/" but the problem persist Any idea please . and many thanks

Comment: i find the solution for this issue for anyone with similar issues : you can simply add rel="external" into the anchor tag as an attribute, this will bypass the ajax transitions and allow the page to load without the error.http://doeswhat.com/2011/03/08/jquery-mobile-error-loading-page/

Comment: You could also return false from the click handler and call preventDefault or stopPropagation to prevent the click event from continuing and trying to follow the link.